# Debugging Spring MVC collection binding

Tags: forms, debugging, spring-mvc, binding, collections

I have a pretty simple user settings form:

```
<form:form method="post" id="fm1" cssClass="fm-v clearfix" commandName="${commandName}" htmlEscape="true">
  <div class="row fl-controls-left">
    <spring:message code="screen.userSettings.label.timeZone.accesskey" var="timeZoneAccessKey" />
    <label for="timeZone" class="fl-label"><spring:message code="screen.userSettings.label.timeZone" /></label>
    <form:select id="timeZone" path="timeZone" accesskey="${timeZoneAccessKey}">
      <form:options items="${user.supportedTimeZones}" itemLabel="label" itemValue="id" />
    </form:select>

    <c:forEach items="${user.answers}" var="answer" varStatus="loop">
      <div class="row fl-controls-left">
        <form:select path="answers[${loop.index}].questionId">
          <option value="-1"><spring:message code="screen.userSettings.question.selectOne" /></option>
          <form:options items="${user.supportedQuestions}" itemLabel="question" itemValue="id" />
        </form:select>
        <form:input path="answers[${loop.index}].answer" size="30" autocomplete="false" htmlEscape="true" type="text" cssClass="required" cssErrorClass="error"/>
      </div>
    </c:forEach>
  </div>
</form:form>
```

Basically, you can set your timezone, and provide answers to a list *forgotten password* questions.  The model object bound to this form is basically this:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8974875234954842283L;

    private List<Answer> answers;
    private List<Question> supportedQuestions;
    private List<TimeZone> supportedTimeZones;
    private String timeZone;

    public User() {
        credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials();
    }

    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public List<Question> getSupportedQuestions() {
        return supportedQuestions;
    }

    public List<TimeZone> getSupportedTimeZones() {
        return supportedTimeZones;
    }

    public String getTimeZone() {
        return timeZone;
    }

    public void setAnswers( List<Answer> answers ) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    public void setSupportedQuestions( List<Question> supportedQuestions ) {
        this.supportedQuestions = supportedQuestions;
    }

    public void setSupportedTimeZones( List<TimeZone> supportedTimeZones ) {
        this.supportedTimeZones = supportedTimeZones;
    }

    public void setTimeZone( String timeZone ) {
        this.timeZone = timeZone;
    }

    ...
}
```

The form displays just fine.  It provides a single drop down showing all supported timezones followed by few rows of question/answer pairs with the questions being drop downs containing all of the supported questions.  When I submit the form back, processing fails because the `List<Answer> answers` is not getting updated with the values from the form.  My question is two fold, first, what did I do wrong?  Second, how should I approach debugging this type of mapping problem in the future?

I have tried stepping through the code with the debugger.  The `setTimeZone()` method is getting called with the value from the form, but the `setAnswers()` method is not.  Nor are the `setQuestionId()` or `setAnswer()` methods of the `Answer` class.  I looked at the `Request` object and it has keys for all the `answer[x].questionId` and `answer[x].answer` parameters, but not sure what the values are.  What would you recommend doing to track down this type of issue?

-------------------------- UPDATE --------------------------------

I just pulled this from the debugger:

```
map[
'answers[4].questionId' -> 'cn=honeymoon,ou=questions,dc=company'
'answers[2].questionId' -> 'cn=honeymoon,ou=questions,dc=company'
'answers[0].questionId' -> 'cn=firstPet,ou=questions,dc=company'
'lt' -> 'LT-786e9b77-efbd-f302-062e-90364cc4634aZe1s2'
'answers[1].answer' -> 'qwer'
'answers[3].answer' -> 'poiu'
'submit' -> 'Save'
'answers[3].questionId' -> 'cn=honeymoon,ou=questions,dc=company'
'answers[1].questionId' -> 'cn=mothersMaiden,ou=questions,dc=company'
'answers[2].answer' -> 'zxcv'
'answers[4].answer' -> 'lkjh'
'timeZone' -> 'America/New_York'
'_eventId' -> 'submit'
'answers[0].answer' -> 'asdf'
]
```

It is what is contained in the requestParameterMap.  Clearly it shows that values were returned for `answers` (both `questionId` and `answer`).  Why is spring not calling `setAnswers()` on the model object (remember that `setTimeZone()` *is* getting called)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be an issue with the binder in the viewState.  It seems like this should work:

```
<binder>
  <binding property="answers" />
  <binding property="timeZone" />
</binder>
```

because `answers` is the property of the bound model object.  However, I actually have to specify the attributes of the elements within the list:

```
<binder>
  <binding property="answers[0].questionId" />
  <binding property="answers[0].answer" />
  <binding property="answers[1].questionId" />
  <binding property="answers[1].answer" />
  <binding property="answers[2].questionId" />
  <binding property="answers[2].answer" />
  <binding property="answers[3].questionId" />
  <binding property="answers[3].answer" />
  <binding property="answers[4].questionId" />
  <binding property="answers[4].answer" />
  <binding property="timeZone" />
</binder>
```

For me this will work (for now) as I have a fixed size number of elements.  Its a little painful to have to include every property of every element in the list, but it works.  There are [bugs/feature requests](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF-1065) filed for this that should make it easier, but until then...